# Constant shape error in simple code

Tags: algorithm, vector, fortran

I have an error with this code and I don't understand why

-"The module or main program array 'u' at (1) must have constant shape."

-Moreover, how can I do this code with a choice of parameters,  I mean [U]=vector(N) where I can chose N and it returns me U.

```
program vector

!declaration

implicit none
integer :: n
integer, parameter :: N=10
real, dimension(N,1) :: U

do n=1,N 
   U(1,N)=n
end do

print*,U
end program vector
```

Comment: Do you really have that first `integer :: n`?

Comment: Or I suppose, do you know that Fortran is not case sensitive (ie., that `n` and `N` refer to the same thing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, Fortran is case**IN**sensitive, so `n` and `N` are the same thing, and you can't declare two different variables/parameters `n` and `N`.

Then you declare `U` to have shape `(N, 1)`, but seem to use it in the form `(1, N)`.

As for how to auto-generate something like `U`, you could use something like this:

```
function vector(n) result(v)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer :: v(n)
    integer :: i
    v = [ (i, i=1, n) ]
    return
end function vector
```

One more thing:

You declare `U` with `dimension(1, N)` which creates a 2D array with one dimension having length 1. I'm wondering whether you wanted to create a 1D array with range from `1` to `N`, for which the declaration would need to be `dimension(1:N)` (or, since Fortran assumes indices start at 1, just `dimension(N)`).

Addressing the questions in your comment:

1. The purpose of `intent(in)` tells the compiler that `n` is only read, not written to, in this function. Considering that you want to use `n` as the size of array `v`, you want that.
2. With `result(v)` I tell the compiler that I want to use the name `v` to refer to the result of the function, not the default (which is the function name). I do this to avoid confusion.
3. `integer :: v(n)` is the same as `integer, dimension(n) :: v`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand almost everything. What is the purpose of " intent(in) "?  And I don't see v(n) in the code, what does it mean?

Comment: I added another comment to the answer, and I answered the questions from your comment.

Comment: What are the advantages of wrapping the array constructor in a function with result an automatic object?

Comment: OP asked how to do `U=vector(N)`, and I didn't see any particular reason not to make this suggestion. For such a simple array, wrapping it into a function is overkill, but if the array were more complex, something like this might make the code more readable. If that is not a good idea at all, then I am keen to learn as to why.